# How can I return a 204 rather than 404 for a missing favicon.ico file in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-204

For my sites I typically have two `server{}` blocks: one serves the site, and the other serves static content for that site from a different domain. Because the `favicon.ico` file is always asked for from the primary domain instead of the static domain, I have to handle that specific file in the site's `server{}` block rather than the static file block.

When a `favicon.ico` file is not found, Nginx returns my define 404 error page, as well as the 404 HTTP status code. However, I don't want to send those bits for my pretty 404 page. ***I want to send a totally empty response with a 204 status code. Below is what I tried, however it does not work. Is there a correct way to do this?*** The idea being that a 204 would indicate a found file, however a totally blank image.

***Also, is my attempt to save bits actually a bad idea?*** If, in fact, returning 204 instead of 404 is a bad idea, is there a more elegant way to return an empty 404 page without creating a new-and-actually-empty file and setting that as the `error_page` directive inside that location block?

```
server {
    ...


    error_page  404          /../static/404.html;

    location @return_204 {
        return  204;
    }

    # Case-insensitive matching of .txt and .xml files.
    # (Example: robots.txt, crossdomain.xml, and sitemap.xml)
    location ~* \.(txt|xml)$ {
        try_files  $uri /../static/$uri;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found  off;
        error_page     404 = @return_204;

        try_files      $uri /../static/$uri;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
         try_files $uri = 204;
}
```

It will try to find the file at the URI or 204 as fallback. 
[Here's the relevant documentation.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)

Comment: For me it worked only when I removed the space between "=" and "204".

Comment: Also, when I add this code I noticed that nginx continues to execute other instructions instead of just give up and return error code.

It did not add additional headers specified below in the nginx.conf if I change 204 to 404.

`
location = /favicon.ico {
         try_files $uri =404;
}

set $TestingThisFix 'test 123';
add_header Testing-This-Fix $TestingThisFix;
`

Comment: I had problems to write code with multiple lines in comments.  Is this feature disabled?

Here is my testing of 404 vs 204 error code:

https://github.com/vstoykovbg/nginx.conf-examples/blob/master/favicon.ico.md

Comment: This will just result in an error. It's **pointing to a file named `204`**: `*60 open() "/etc/nginx/html204" failed (2: No such file or directory)`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple

```
location /favicon.ico { return 204; }
```

would be the easiest.

Comment: I want it to return the ico if it exists, though, hence the try_files and setting of a 404 handler to return the 204.

Comment: Have you added a location @return_204 .... section then to handle this? when you define a specific event you need to handle this event in a separate block.

Answer (score 0):

The **important** bit is that the `=` and the HTTP status Code need to be *one* word and there must *not* be any space between. If you leave a space between, your `error.log` will fill quickly as 95% of all requests have a `favicon.ico` of some sort.

The following should be saved for reusability and just `include`d where necessary.

```
# (i) No need to log presence or absence.
location = /favicon.ico {
  access_log     off;
  log_not_found  off;
  try_files      $uri  =204;
}
```